# How to draw smooth lines in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Using Kivy, I'm trying to draw 1 long blue line with various points and the line looks fuzzy and jagged in certain places. I tried using a texture and adjusting the line width but the issue remains. Does anyone know how to make the lines look consistent and sharp?

[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line, InstructionGroup, Canvas, CanvasBase, Color

GRADIENT_DATA = (
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x07\x07\x07\x0f\x0f\x0f\x17\x17\x17\x1f\x1f\x1f"
    b"'''///777???GGGOOOWWW___gggooowww\x7f\x7f\x7f\x87\x87\x87"
    b"\x8f\x8f\x8f\x97\x97\x97\x9f\x9f\x9f\xa7\xa7\xa7\xaf\xaf\xaf"
    b"\xb7\xb7\xb7\xbf\xbf\xbf\xc7\xc7\xc7\xcf\xcf\xcf\xd7\xd7\xd7"
    b"\xdf\xdf\xdf\xe7\xe7\xe7\xef\xef\xef\xf7\xf7\xf7\xff\xff\xff"
    b"\xf6\xf6\xf6\xee\xee\xee\xe6\xe6\xe6\xde\xde\xde\xd5\xd5\xd5"
    b"\xcd\xcd\xcd\xc5\xc5\xc5\xbd\xbd\xbd\xb4\xb4\xb4\xac\xac\xac"
    b"\xa4\xa4\xa4\x9c\x9c\x9c\x94\x94\x94\x8b\x8b\x8b\x83\x83\x83"
    b"{{{sssjjjbbbZZZRRRJJJAAA999111)))   \x18\x18\x18\x10\x10\x10"
    b"\x08\x08\x08\x00\x00\x00")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        widget = Widget()
        # Create texture
        tex = Texture.create(size=(1, 64), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        tex.blit_buffer(GRADIENT_DATA, colorfmt='rgb')
        # Draw lines with the texture
        with widget.canvas:
            Color(.157, .588, .988)
            Line(points=(100, 100, 120, 96, 140, 103, 160, 130, 180, 150, 200, 122, 220, 170, 240, 200, 
            260, 215, 280, 197, 300, 230, 320, 280, 340, 300, 360, 275, 380, 295, 400, 320, 420, 340, 
            440, 380, 460, 340,  480, 400, 500, 420, 520, 460, 540, 430, 560, 480, 580, 520, 600, 560, 
            620, 590, 640, 480, 660, 500, 680, 600, 700, 580, 720, 590, 740, 610, 760, 630, 780, 400, 
            800, 430, 820, 460, 840, 500, 860, 520, 880, 560, 900, 490, 920, 460, 940, 525, 960, 500, 
            980, 560, 1000, 530, 1020, 610, 1040, 630, 1060, 680), width=.75, texture=tex)
        return widget

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: You could try using the SmoothLine class, which exists essentially to fix this issue but may have some issues as it stands. You could also check if you have antialiasing enabled (MSAA in Kivy settings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a decent way to create a smooth line by utilizing the following:

1. Utilize a texture for the line - not sure why this matters but it looks worse without it..
2. Make sure to draw the line with a canvas on top of a child widget within an effect widget. Within the effect widget, we must utilize blur effects to reduce jaggedness.

Here is the code:

```
#We use a combination of the following to create a smooth line:
#1) Utilize a texture for the line - not sure why this matters but it looks worse without it..
#2) Make sure to draw the line with a canvas on top of a child widget within an effect widget. Within the effect widget, we must utilize blur effects to reduce jaggedness.
#it should be structured like this:

    #Effect Widget:
        #Widget: <- note extra widget here
            #canvas for the line

#NOTE: If you don't nest the canvas this way the blur effects won't work on the line.
#Costs and benefits of this approach: You will take a hit on performance and the color of the line will darken a bit, but at least it won't look jagged. 
#You can add more brightness to the line by adding more white (\xff) into the gradient data. 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line, InstructionGroup, Canvas, CanvasBase, Color, Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.effectwidget import EffectWidget
from kivy.uix.effectwidget import (MonochromeEffect,
                                   InvertEffect,
                                   ScanlinesEffect,
                                   ChannelMixEffect,
                                   ScanlinesEffect,
                                   FXAAEffect,
                                   PixelateEffect,
                                   HorizontalBlurEffect,
                                   VerticalBlurEffect)

Builder.load_string("""
#: import ew kivy.uix.effectwidget
<MyApp>: 
    EffectWidget:
        effects: ew.HorizontalBlurEffect(size=2), ew.VerticalBlurEffect(size=2), ew.FXAAEffect()
        Widget:
            id: ef_widget
""")

GRADIENT_DATA_DARKER = (
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x07\x07\x07\x0f\x0f\x0f\x17\x17\x17\x1f\x1f\x1f"
    b"'''///777???GGGOOOWWW___gggooowww\x7f\x7f\x7f\x87\x87\x87"
    b"\x8f\x8f\x8f\x97\x97\x97\x9f\x9f\x9f\xa7\xa7\xa7\xaf\xaf\xaf"
    b"\xb7\xb7\xb7\xbf\xbf\xbf\xc7\xc7\xc7\xcf\xcf\xcf\xd7\xd7\xd7"
    b"\xdf\xdf\xdf\xe7\xe7\xe7\xef\xef\xef\xf7\xf7\xf7\xff\xff\xff"
    b"\xf6\xf6\xf6\xee\xee\xee\xe6\xe6\xe6\xde\xde\xde\xd5\xd5\xd5"
    b"\xcd\xcd\xcd\xc5\xc5\xc5\xbd\xbd\xbd\xb4\xb4\xb4\xac\xac\xac"
    b"\xa4\xa4\xa4\x9c\x9c\x9c\x94\x94\x94\x8b\x8b\x8b\x83\x83\x83"
    b"{{{sssjjjbbbZZZRRRJJJAAA999111)))   \x18\x18\x18\x10\x10\x10"
    b"\x08\x08\x08\x00\x00\x00")

GRADIENT_DATA_BRIGHTER = (
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x07\x07\x07\x0f\x0f\x0f\x17\x17\x17\x1f\x1f\x1f"
    b"'''///777???GGGOOOWWW___gggooowww\x7f\x7f\x7f\x87\x87\x87"
    b"\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xaf\xaf\xaf"
    b"\xff\xff\xff\xbf\xbf\xbf\xc7\xc7\xc7\xcf\xcf\xcf\xff\xff\xff"
    b"\xff\xff\xff\xe7\xe7\xe7\xef\xef\xef\xf7\xf7\xf7\xff\xff\xff"
    b"\xff\xff\xff\xee\xee\xee\xe6\xe6\xe6\xde\xde\xde\xff\xff\xff"
    b"\xff\xff\xff\xc5\xc5\xc5\xbd\xbd\xbd\xb4\xb4\xb4\xff\xff\xff"
    b"\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x94\x94\x94\x8b\x8b\x8b\x83\x83\x83"
    b"{{{sssjjjbbbZZZRRRJJJAAA999111)))   \x18\x18\x18\x10\x10\x10"
    b"\x08\x08\x08\x00\x00\x00")

class MyApp(App, FloatLayout):
    def build(self):
        # Create 1st texture
        tex = Texture.create(size=(1, 64), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        tex.blit_buffer(GRADIENT_DATA_DARKER, colorfmt='rgb')
        mypoints = [100, 100, 120, 96, 140, 103, 160, 130, 180, 150, 200, 122, 220, 170, 240, 200, 
            260, 215, 280, 197, 300, 230, 320, 280, 340, 300, 360, 275, 380, 295, 400, 320, 420, 340, 
            440, 380, 460, 340,  480, 400, 500, 420, 520, 460, 540, 430, 560, 480, 580, 520, 600, 560, 
            620, 590, 640, 480, 660, 500, 680, 600, 700, 580, 720, 590, 740, 610, 760, 630, 780, 400]
        with self.ids.ef_widget.canvas:
            Color(.157, .588, .988) #rgb = 40, 150, 252
            Line(points=(mypoints), width=2.2, texture=tex) #this line is darker because the gradient doesn't have as much white in it..
        # Create 2nd texture
        tex2 = Texture.create(size=(1, 64), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        tex2.blit_buffer(GRADIENT_DATA_BRIGHTER, colorfmt='rgb')
        mypoints2 = [300, 100, 320, 96, 340, 103, 360, 130, 380, 150, 400, 122, 420, 170, 440, 200, 
            460, 215, 480, 197, 500, 230, 520, 280, 540, 300, 560, 275, 580, 295, 600, 320, 620, 340, 
            640, 380, 660, 340,  680, 400, 700, 420, 720, 460, 740, 430, 760, 480, 780, 520, 800, 560, 
            820, 590, 840, 480, 860, 500, 880, 600, 900, 580, 920, 590, 940, 610, 960, 630, 980, 400]
        with self.ids.ef_widget.canvas:
            Color(.157, .588, .988) #rgb = 40, 150, 252
            Line(points=(mypoints2), width=2.2, texture=tex2) #this line is brighter because the gradient has more white in it (more \xff)
        #here is what the 2 gradients look like as rectangles - the one with more white results in a brighter line
        with self.ids.ef_widget.canvas:
            Rectangle(size=[100, 100], pos=[900, 700], texture=tex2)
        with self.ids.ef_widget.canvas:
            Rectangle(size=[100, 100], pos=[700, 700], texture=tex)
        #here is how you can convert from int to bytes (for use in gradients above) or from bytes to ints
        print (str(bytes([255]))) #convert int to bytes (r/g/b number)
        print (str(int.from_bytes(b'\x00', byteorder='big'))) #convert bytes to int
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    MyApp().run()
```

As you can see, the line looks much smoother now:

[image]